# HTMLの「ファイルを開く」ダイアログが表示されない場合がある

Tags: html

HTMLにて、画像ボタンをクリックしたら「ファイルを開く」ダイアログを表示する機能を作成しています。

画像ボタンをクリックしても「ファイルを開く」ダイアログが現れないというユーザがいました。
当方の環境で確認をしましたが、再現しません。
どのような条件で「『ファイルを開く』ダイアログが現れないことがおこりえる」と考えられるでしょうか。

```
<html>
<div>
<label for="FileOpen">
<input id="FileOpen" type="file" name="File" class="FileOpen" style="display: none;"> 
<img src="./Test.png" border="0" style="cursor:pointer;">
</label>
</div>
</html>
```

補足:
当方、ユーザ共にブラウザは Edge または Chromeを使用しています。
Webサーバは Raspberry Pi OS (Django)を使用しています。

Comment: > `当方、ユーザ共にブラウザは Edge または Chromeを使用しています。` というのは、両者がEdgeとChromeの両方を試して、ユーザー側のブラウザではどちらもダイアログが現れないのだが、質問者の環境ではどちらのブラウザでも再現しない、という意味でしょうか？

Comment: 当方、ユーザ共にどちらのブラウザも使用しています。ユーザ側のブラウザでは、Edgeで確認したときにダイアログが現れないが、当方ではどちらのブラウザでも再現しません。

Answer (score 1):

質問文から読み取れる内容だけだと関係があるかは何とも言えませんが、似た様な体験をしたことがありますので、ご参考までに回答させていただこうと思います。

私の場合、ボタンが押せない、と連絡してきたユーザがブラウザのズーム機能を使って100%以外の表示をしていました。
そのため、ギリギリでレイアウトしていた画面の配置が一部崩れて、`<div>`だったか別の要素の領域の後に画像が配置され、見えてはいるもののいくら押しても反応しない、という現象が発生していました。

可能であれば現象が発生しているユーザのブラウザのズーム率なども確認してみてはどうでしょうか。解決のヒントになれば幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

自分も画像ボタンをクリックしても「ファイルを開く」ダイアログが現れないことは
なかったですが(EdgeとIEモード、Chrome)、ソースに`<div>`が抜けてました。